# fnproject ui unable to load apps

Tags: fn

Was trying to launch the fnproject ui and check for the apps deployed. However in the browser it doesn't load the app and is stuck at loading....message. In the command line i see something like below. Any idea what maybe causing this.

command line logs are as below:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --link functions:api -p 4000:4000 --name fnui -e "API_URL=http://api:8080" fnproject/ui
Unable to find image 'fnproject/ui:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from fnproject/ui
e110a4a17941: Pull complete 
3c5dcb228286: Pull complete 
19c9e79b9f16: Pull complete 
78d32a0bd7e8: Pull complete 
a2337500ed47: Pull complete 
12f394f0e817: Pull complete 
64e0f96a7b8c: Pull complete 
f977f532237b: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6d82707c6462e99d46c33ab6f7a502548f802f2d8f0ed830f568e7eda4a64f81
Status: Downloaded newer image for fnproject/ui:latest
```

> FunctionsUI@0.0.16 start /app
>   node server

Using API url: api:8080
Server running on port 4000
GET http://api:8080/v1/apps, params:  {}
....
....

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if there was a problem with version 16 of the UI image. Please pull down a new image using
`docker pull fnproject/ui`and try again.

If you're using the newer version should see the following at startup

```
> FunctionsUI@0.0.17 start /app
> node server
```

Comment: Pulled the latest image 
> FunctionsUI@0.0.17 start /app
> node server
But the error persists...

Error. Api responded with  502 Can not parse api response

Comment: The 502 sounds like a proxy issue. Is Docker is configured to use a proxy server? If so `api` needs to be in the exclude list to allow the ui server to connect to the Fn server.